# Text fetched from database is shown in single line not in correct formate

Tags: php, database

I just created an aplication where is use php to save tasks and display them on dashboard
[html form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDzAf.png)

it saving the the data in correct formate
[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIdnp.png)
but the problem is when I fectch that data and show it on dashboard it shows in a single line.
[output on html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRFHQ.png)
i want that to apear normaly with line breaks but i don't know why it's not adding linebreaks while displaying data

I tried to find a way to sove this problem but no success

Comment: It's not adding new lines because html has no idea what \n is. You need to add in formatting. check out [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're putting the contents of that textarea directly into html.
In textarea in forms, linebreaks are displayed as expected. But outside of forms, html does not format linebreaks (it collapses all whitespace in to a single space).
There are various ways to create linebreaks in html, but the simplest method here would be to replace the linebreak with the <br/> tag. php even has a function to do this nl2br()

It's worth noting, though, that posting user input without sanitizing it can result in Cross-site scripting attacks (https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) that allow malicious users to run arbitrary javascript in your users' browsers.